# Jasper Reports 5: Title Band, how to create a footer?

Tags: jasper-reports

i have a title band.  my report is landscape 595 by 842.  i simply want the title band to take up a full page and be able to add text to the very bottom of that title page/band.

i have tried position fix relative to bottom.  it still floats up.  i have tried making the title band 559 high (with 36 top margin to make 595).  that works except there is tons of white space and so if something on the title expands (dynamic data) the text at title page bottom breaks to second page.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  Problem is that title band does not stretch, so fix relative to bottom does not work.  Solution is to add a background band, height of report (minus margin).  Then put page footer there, is will show on title and all other pages.  Then add a blank page footer to save white space for the real footer in the background.  done.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **only** the `pageFooter` and then if you only like it to display on first page use the `printWhenExpression`.

```
<pageFooter>
    <band height="50">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()==1]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="dd4c229b-7453-4026-b01e-cfc325053335"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["You will only see me on first page"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

Note the `pageFooter` will be present on every page (even if blank), this is the famous [firstPageFooter](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/2732-0) request / tracker, but this seems not to be your case since you are already adding it later...

Comment: page footer does not print on title.   what I want is actually a page footer that prints on every page including the title page/band.  the background solutions  (other answer) is a kludge for sure.  but it works.

Comment: This depends on the dimension of the title band, try to make it smaller and you will have pageFooter on first page... (can't really see the use of your solution...) anyway have fun...